# checking if record already exists before inserting ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `diver` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `registrated`)
        SELECT '$fname', '$lname', now()
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT firstname, lastname FROM `diver` WHERE diver.firstname = '$fname' AND diver.lastname = '$lname')";
```

i get this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT firstname, lastname FROM `diver` WHERE diver.firstname =' at line 3

the code works perfectly fine in localhost, but when in my online database it's not. is there any other solution that will do the exact same thing?

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Munging query strings with parameter values just leads to hard-to-fix syntax errors.

Comment: Your example code and the error you mention aren't the same, there is no `FROM` after `now() WHERE`

Comment: The error you are showing cannot be the result of that query. Another query seems to be failing instead.

Comment: edited^, been trying different solutions, should be correct now

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use parameters.  In MySQL, you need a `from` to use `where`.  One method is to use `from dual` (adopted from Oracle).

I tend to go for:

```
INSERT INTO `diver` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `registrated`)
    SELECT fname, lname, now()
    FROM (SELECT ? as fname, ? as lname) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM `diver` d
                      WHERE d.firstname = x.fname AND
                            d.lastname = x.lname
                     );
```

I assume you intend `not exists`, because inserting rows with duplicate values is not usually what one wants to do.

Actually, this isn't the best approach.  Instead, create a unique index/constraint on the name columns:

```
create unique index unq_diver_firstname_lastname on diver(firstname, lastname);

insert into `diver` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `registrated`)
     values (?, ?, now())
     on duplicate key update firstname = values(firstname);
```

This does nothing when a duplicate is inserted.

Also note that names are not necessarily unique, so checking for uniqueness of names might not be a good idea in general.